# Error at admin on clicking 'ship' at some orders using USPS?

Tags: magento-1, magento-1.6

I am using magento 1.6, i am using USPS for shipping when i anybody create order and at admin panel when i click ship for the order it throws error :

```
   Invalid method Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Usps::isGirthAllowed(Array
  (
   [0] => FR
  )
  )
```

Does anybody come across this and solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't happen unless your core is modified, or the class `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Usps` is copied in the local folder and modified in there.
In the core file this method exists so this issue shouldn't appear:

```
public function isGirthAllowed($countyDest = null)
{
    return $this->_isUSCountry($countyDest) ? false : true;
}
```